# I don't want vertical scroll bar for my website in any screen ( starting from 1280 px to 1920 px)

Tags: html, css

I am developing desktop web application which will supports laptop (1024 * 768) to big screen(1920 * 1080). In big screen I am not getting vertical scroll bar. But in all small screens I am getting vertical scroll bar. This scroll bar is common because I have more content. But I don't want scroll bar. Is there any way to implement like this (or) please help me to implement only height based media queries in CSS . I need exact media queries which related to height based for each screen start from 1024 * 768 to 1920 * 1080.

Answer (score 1):

This pice of code will detect you when your resolution is between these values and will your ID or class or whatever you need with an auto scroll if the content can fill it or not.

If you don't have enought content the scroll won't show up.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) , screen and (max-width: 1920px) {
        #yourID{  overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: auto; }                     
}
```

or if you want hide the scroll you just have to write:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) , screen and (max-width: 1920px) {
        #yourID{  overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; }                     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **@media** in css

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 767px)
{ 
    .container{width:100%;overflow:hidden;}
    //add all the classes and ids which you want to make responsive here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a **hack** I used, and it´s maybe why your question has been downvoted.

In your  section add:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

and in your body or main div´s css add:

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
```